# PowerShell Extracting multiple email domains from a single row within a CSV

Tags: regex, powershell

I am very new to PowerShell and I am having trouble with this task.

I need to be able to extract multiple emails with the same domain from one row within a CSV file.

This is what i had originally, but it stops after it finds a match.

```
$myvar = @()
foreach($row in $CSV)
{ 
    If ($row.ProxyAddresses -match "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@markelintl.ca")
    {
       $myvar += $Matches[0]
    } 
}
```

I am confident i need to use `Select-String` with `-allMatches` and i found this example :

```
Select-String "@([a-z1-9\.-]+)" -AllMatches | 
      Select-Object $row. Matches | 
      Select-Object Groups | 
      ForEach{$_.Groups[1]} | 
      Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```

But I am having trouble matching my variables into this (due to my novice ability).

Is Select-String my best bet in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how the ProxyAdresses are stored in your CSV, you could do this:

```
$myvar = $CSV.ProxyAddresses | ForEach-Object { 
    [regex]::Matches($_, '(?im)([\w-+.'']+@markelintl\.ca)').Value
}
```

---

If you want to extract emailaddresses from multiple domains, I would suggest first create an array of domains (the part after the `@`) and from that create the regex:

```
# the array of domains (without prefix @); not escaped in any way
$domains = 'markelintl.ca', 'somecompany.com', 'anotherinstitution.org'  # etc.

# now create a regular expression out of the $domains array that will look like this:
# (?im)([\w-+.']+@(?:markelintl\.ca|somecompany\.com|anotherinstitution\.org))
# we'll use the [regex]::Escape() method to do the heavy lifting
# see explanation below
$regex = '(?im)([\w-+.'']+@(?:{0}))' -f (($domains | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')

# then loop over the ProxyAddresses like before:
$myvar = $CSV.ProxyAddresses | ForEach-Object { 
    [regex]::Matches($_, $regex).Value
}
```

**Regex explanation:**

```
(?                                Use these options for the whole regular expression
   i                              Case insensitive
   m                              ^$ match at line breaks
)                                
(                                 Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [\w-+.']                       Match a single character present in the list below
                                  A “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
                                  A single character from the list “-+.'”
      +                           Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   @                              Match the character “@” literally
   (?:                            Match the regular expression below
                                  Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         markelintl               Match the character string “markelintl” literally (case insensitive)
         \.                       Match the character “.” literally
         ca                       Match the character string “ca” literally (case insensitive)
      |                          
                                  Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         somecompany              Match the character string “somecompany” literally (case insensitive)
         \.                       Match the character “.” literally
         com                      Match the character string “com” literally (case insensitive)
      |                          
                                  Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
         anotherinstitution       Match the character string “anotherinstitution” literally (case insensitive)
         \.                       Match the character “.” literally
         org                      Match the character string “org” literally (case insensitive)
   )
)
```

**Special Characters in Regex that need escaping if they are to be treated literally**

| Char | Description | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \ | Backslash | Used to escape a special character |
| ^ | Caret | Beginning of a string |
| $ | Dollar sign | End of a string |
| . | Period or dot | Matches any single character |
| | | Vertical bar or pipe symbol | Matches previous OR next character/group |
| ? | Question mark | Match zero or one of the previous |
| * | Asterisk or star | Match zero, one or more of the previous |
| + | Plus sign | Match one or more of the previous |
| ( ) | Opening and closing parenthesis | Group characters |
| [ ] | Opening and closing square bracket | Matches a range of characters |
| { } | Opening and closing curly brace | Matches a specified number of occurrences of the previous |

Comment: This got the job done thank you!

Picked up the learn PowerShell in 30 days of lunches book and I am reading heavily.

Comment: May i ask what is the purpose of the \ in @markelintl\.ca?  I have to run this for multiple domains and was going to add them in behind it.  Unless its better to run them invidivually?

Comment: The dot needs to be escaped with a backslash for regex in order to yreat it as literal character. Without that, it means _any character_. There are more special characters with regex.

Comment: @Justin.Raiford Please see my edit where I have added explanation for the regex and show you how you can easily add more domains to check for in the code. BTW. If you feel my answer solves your problem, please have a quick read of the [tour] where you can see how to mark a question 'done/solved'.

Comment: Really appreciate your guidance, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you change the part where you add the address to your array.

Try something like this:

```
$myvar = @()
foreach($row in $CSV)
{ 
    If ($row.ProxyAddresses -match "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@markelintl.ca")
    {
       $myvar += $row.ProxyAddresses
    } 
}
```

To give you a more specific answer, it would be helpful to have a sample of the CSV with test data.

Hope that helps!